# Use actionButton to send email in RShiny

Tags: html, css, r, button, shiny

I'm working on a web app in Shiny. I'm pretty familiar with R but my knowledge of HTML, CSS, jQuery, etc is lacking which makes formatting things nicely challenging.

I want to include an `actionButton` that the user can click on to send an email to the administrator in case of questions or concerns. Here's what I have so far, which kind of works but is pretty heinous:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Set layout/format for app
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("download_data", "Download this Data"),
      br(),
      actionButton(inputId = "email1", 
                   icon = icon("envelope", lib = "font-awesome"), 
                   a("Contact Admin", 
                       href="mailto:my_awesome_email_address.com"))
    ),
    mainPanel(),
    position = "left"
  )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If possible, I'd like to keep using the `actionButton` or something similar in order to keep the same button format across both buttons.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, well this is annoying. Hate to be one of those people that answers his own question, but here goes:

I toyed around with the ordering of the different `tags` in my code and realized that my current code was wrong because I was only stating that I wanted the text of the button to link to my email address and not the button itself. To fix this, I flipped the nesting of the `actionButton` and the `a()` tag to get the following:

```
a(actionButton(inputId = "email1", label = "Contact Admin", 
                 icon = icon("envelope", lib = "font-awesome")),
    href="mailto:my_awesome_email_address.com")
```

Clicking anywhere on the button automatically opens up an email addressed to the given email address after the `mailto` argument. No extra HTML or CSS coding required. Hope this helps someone else so they can spend their time doing something more valuable than scouring the internet for hours on end.

Comment: With newest shiny version this does not work anymore and broke my app.